Uniform convergence; L1
I am tasked with finding a sequence of functions, each integrable, but converging uniformly to a function that is non integrable.
My idea is to consider the interval [0,1] and $f_{n}= \chi_{[-n,n]}$ with counting measure. Then, on [0,1], $f_{n}$ converges to 1 uniformly, but the integral of 1 with respect to the counting measure is infinite. Does this make sense or should I modify my approach?

But with respect to counting measure, it is not. Right?

On $[0,1]$ your $f_n$ is same as $f$ and it is not integrable.

What do you mean by $[-n,n]$? Do you mean ${-n,-n+1,...,1,2,...n}$? or do you mean the real interval $[-n,n]={x\in\Bbb{R}:-n\leq x\leq n}$? In the latter case, the use of counting measure is counter-intuitive as the support is not a countable set. If you mean the first case, then the functions $f_{n}$ don't converge uniformly to $1$.

I meant the continuous interval.

@user873295 In that case you need to mention the space or support on which you have defined your counting measure. You need to say that the counting measure is supported on a countable set like say $\Bbb{Z}$.

If you want an example using the counting measure on $\Bbb{Z}$ or say $\Bbb{N}$, then take the space to be $(\Bbb{N},2^{\Bbb{N}},\mu_{c})$, where $\mu_{c}$ denotes counting measure.
Take $f_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\chi_{\{k\}}$. Or in simpler notation $f_{n}(k)=\frac{1}{k}$ if $1\leq k\leq n$ and is $0$ for $k\geq n+1$
Then see that $f_{n}$ converges uniformly to the function $f(k)=\frac{1}{k}$ for all $k\in\Bbb{N}$.
Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Find $N$ such that $n\geq N\implies \frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$.
Then for all $k\in\Bbb{N}$, for all $n\geq N$, you have $|f_{n}(k)-f(k)|\leq\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$ because $f_{n}(k)-f(k)=0$ for $k=1,2,...,n$ and for $k\geq n+1$, you have $|f_{n}(k)-f(k)|=|f(k)|=\frac{1}{k}\leq \frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$.
But you know that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f(k)=\infty$ whereas $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_{n}(k)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}<\infty$ for each $n$.

Thank you for your help!

On $(1,\infty)$ with Lebesgue measure, take $f_n=\frac 1 x \chi_{(1,n)}$ and $f(x)=\frac 1  x$.

How is the uniform convergence condition met?

Outside $(1,n)$, we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\frac  1 x <\frac 1 n <\epsilon$ whenever $n >\frac 1 {\epsilon}$. @user873295

Thank you. I appreciate it!
